# Is this a good bluff-shove with AK on the flop?

Tags: texas-hold-em, betting-strategy, no-limit, range

I was playing a hand at 2/5 cents NL Hold'em online, and I was unsure about whether or not my thought process was good or not. I was in MP, the villain was small blind. I'm asking specifically with this hand because it's a big hand with AKo. I had only been at the table for around 30 hands or so, and I haven't noticed any specific tendencies from this player. and I'm around 110 deep as the smaller stack.

I'm dealt AKo, it folds to me (MP) and I bet 3.5x, there are two callers between me and villain (SB), and villain raises to around 18x. BB folds and it's back to me, I four-bet to around 50x  the villain calls and its heads up between us. So far I think this is okay but I am open to criticism.

The flop comes 9 8 4 rainbow, villain checks and my thought process is as follows: my opponent doesn't have AA or KK in their range, most players I think are also five-betting with QQ pre-flop, so he has AK, AQ,  some QQ, and maybe JJ and 10s if they are loose. I have AA and KK in my range, and I can probably get my opponent to fold a lot of strong hands if I shove. Worst case I have some equity against everything, so I shove around 65x and I get called. Villain shows QQ (and I lose). Was this a bad bet?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the four-bet around 50x is not a good idea. At this stage, the range of villain includes AA, KK, QQ and AKs and you are not a favourite against these hands. Moreover, you are now more or less committed and when villain calls, he is also committed. This means that villain would lose a lot of equity by not calling you on the river, so I think your argument about your fold equity is also not correct.

Answer (score 0):

IN PENNY BLIND GAMES PLAYERS ALMOST NEVER FOLD.THIER INABILITY TO FIGURE OUT HOE BAD THE PRICE THYE ARE PAYIN IS ONE OF THE THINGS THAT MAKE THEM BAD PLAYERS. YOU TAKE ADVANTAGE OF THAT WHEN YOU HIT A HAND. IF THE PLAYER HAD POCKET DUECES BEFORE THR FLOP HE/SHE/ WAS THE FAVORITE BY A FEW POINTS.
ak PLAYS BETTER AGAINST A LAGER FIELD, SO WHILE YOU DO WANT TO RAISE, A BIG RAISE THAT RUNS PLAYERS OFF IS WEAK. A SMALLER RAISE THAT SWEETENS THE POT AND HOOKS WEAK HANDS THAT ARE NOT LIKELY TO BEAT YOUR HAND WHEN YOU BOTH CONNECT   WITH AN ACE OR A KING IS BETTER ev. with a pair of queens your raise thinned thE field which made it much better for the pocket QQ'S PUDHING WITH AK is a short stacked tournament play not a cash game play.

Comment: I think you might have had CAPS lock on accidentally when you wrote this Jon ;)

Comment: or having an angry day.